# Integral involving modified Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

I would like to calculate the closed-form expression for the following integral:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{M}\exp(-\frac{x}{a})K_{\nu}(b\sqrt{1+x})\mathrm{d}x,$$
where $M$, $a$, and $b$ are all positive constants. Note that $K_{\nu}(\cdot)$ is a modified Bessel's function of the second kind.

I have unsuccessfully tried substituting $\sqrt{1+x}$ by a variable $u$.

Comment: What is $\nu$? Is it a real number, complex number or what?

Comment: \nu is a positive integer.

Comment: As a first step I would put $\sqrt{1+x}=y+1$, then $x=y^2+2y$ and the limits of integration stay the same.

Comment: Then I would use the integral representation of the Bessel function: $$ K_n(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x \cosh(t)} \cosh(n t) dt$$ and exchange the order of the integration. I'm not sure it will lead to a closed form (if it exists) but this is what I would do. Maybe I'll post an answer later

Comment: Btw, if $M$ was also a positive integer, it would make the problem much more simple